# How to make an embedded Youtube video automatically start playing?

Tags: iframe, video, youtube, embed

In my project, there is a video gallery module. In this module, there are two options: direct FLV uploading, and adding a video embed code from YouTube.

I am writing some embed code for a div element (actually, the embed code comes from database). I want to make this video begin playing automatically.

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zGPuazETKkI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This is a sample embed code from YouTube. I want to make this video play automatically using JavaScript.

Comment: Just remember, most people don't want audio/video blaring at them without their consent. There's a reason we **hate** a/v ads and want them to die with fire.

Comment: autoplay is not widely available anymore

Answer (score 73):

You have to use

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zGPuazETKkI?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

`?autoplay=1`

and not

`&autoplay=1`

its the first URL param so its added with a ?

Comment: thanks this worked for me! this was inserted right after the embed code from You tube. ;autoplay=1" this was the original code:
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_5nrEUdCfd4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> It worked when the edit was inserted behind the: rel=0"
before the frameborde

Comment: Only way I could get this to work was by removing the `rel=0` param. (not sure what that does anywho).

Comment: `rel=0` removes the related suggested videos at the end.

Answer (score 8):

This works perfectly for me try this just put ?rel=0&autoplay=1 in the end of link

```
<iframe width="631" height="466" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UUdMixCYeTA?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<iframe title='YouTube video player' class='youtube-player' type='text/html'
        width='030' height='030'
        src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZFo8b9DbcMM?rel=0&border=&autoplay=1'
        type='application/x-shockwave-flash'
        allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true'
        frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

just insert your code after embed/

Answer (score 3):

Add **&autoplay=1** to your syntax, like this

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zGPuazETKkI&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: According to related questions you would want to add `?autoplay=1`.  As is standard in URL paramters, the first is identified by an `?` and other appended using the `&amp;` symbol.