# Start a YouTube video when website opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I'd like for a YouTube video to start playing right away with the sound muted when a user opens my webpage, but when embedding it from YouTube the user has to click on it and click "play" in order for the video to start playing.

Right now I get a code like this from YouTube:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M0NXSdLlaZ4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And I'm not sure how to get the YouTube video to start playing as soon as the user opens the website.

Comment: You seem to have omitted the code that you get from Youtube?

Comment: @DanielArthur Sorry about that, it wasn't showing up (maybe SO tried to embed it) I have updated the question to show the embed code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer:

[How to make an embedded Youtube video automatically start playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349716/how-to-make-an-embedded-youtube-video-automatically-start-playing)

It says to add `?autoplay=1` like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M0NXSdLlaZ4?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: she works!!! does it always get started with the sound off? (i want to make sure the video doesnt start with sound on so as not to surprise my users)

Comment: You can add an **id** to the `<iframe>` and add a javascript code to mute the video like this:


`<iframe id ="myvideo" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M0NXSdLlaZ4?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

**The javascript code:**


`var myVideo =  iframe.getElementById('myvideo'); 
myVideo.mute();`

Hope it helps you,